# Ethernet stop working

Tags: networking, internet, ethernet

My ethernet has stopped working, I am currently on Xubuntu 16.04 but it stopped quite a few updates back. By "has stopped working" I mean that one day was working and the day after it wasn't after and update. Since then I've been using the WiFi but now I need Ethernet to start working again.

I've seen this issue is quite common and I've tried different things but none of them have worked (besides the fact that I am afraid to break something). I am going to be as descriptive as I can:

1) The "internet/connected" icon at the top displays fine when Ethernet cable is not present. If I plug it, it gets thinking and thinking and never stops although there is a wired connection detected.

2) `ifconfing`:

```
enp0s6    Link encap:Ethernet  direcciónHW 00:1e:68:36:c3:42  
          Dirección inet6: fe80::bab8:6bd3:d198:9f52/64 Alcance:Enlace
          ACTIVO DIFUSIÓN FUNCIONANDO MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Métrica:1
          Paquetes RX:0 errores:0 perdidos:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          Paquetes TX:723 errores:0 perdidos:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          colisiones:0 long.colaTX:1000 
          Bytes RX:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:120442 (120.4 KB)

lo        Link encap:Bucle local  
          Direc. inet:127.0.0.1  Másc:255.0.0.0
          Dirección inet6: ::1/128 Alcance:Anfitrión
          ACTIVO BUCLE FUNCIONANDO  MTU:65536  Métrica:1
          Paquetes RX:2451 errores:0 perdidos:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          Paquetes TX:2451 errores:0 perdidos:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          colisiones:0 long.colaTX:1000 
          Bytes RX:228341 (228.3 KB)  TX bytes:228341 (228.3 KB)

wlp3s0    Link encap:Ethernet  direcciónHW 00:1f:3a:76:74:2e  
          Direc. inet:192.168.1.128  Difus.:192.168.1.255  Másc:255.255.255.0
          Dirección inet6: fe80::e23d:c05d:c1c5:4a12/64 Alcance:Enlace
          ACTIVO DIFUSIÓN FUNCIONANDO MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Métrica:1
          Paquetes RX:36717 errores:0 perdidos:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          Paquetes TX:28446 errores:0 perdidos:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          colisiones:0 long.colaTX:1000 
          Bytes RX:36576237 (36.5 MB)  TX bytes:6198839 (6.1 MB)
```

3) `sudo lshw -c network -sanitize`:

```
*-network               
       descripción: Ethernet interface
       producto: MCP65 Ethernet
       fabricante: NVIDIA Corporation
       id físico: 6
       información del bus: pci@0000:00:06.0
       nombre lógico: enp0s6
       versión: a3
       serie: [REMOVED]
       tamaño: 1Gbit/s
       capacidad: 1Gbit/s
       anchura: 32 bits
       reloj: 66MHz
       capacidades: pm bus_master cap_list ethernet physical mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuración: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=forcedeth driverversion=0.64 duplex=full latency=0 link=yes maxlatency=20 mingnt=1 multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
       recursos: irq:20 memoria:f2487000-f2487fff ioport:30e0(size=8)
  *-network
       descripción: Interfaz inalámbrica
       producto: AR242x / AR542x Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express)
       fabricante: Qualcomm Atheros
       id físico: 0
       información del bus: pci@0000:03:00.0
       nombre lógico: wlp3s0
       versión: 01
       serie: [REMOVED]
       anchura: 64 bits
       reloj: 33MHz
       capacidades: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuración: broadcast=yes driver=ath5k driverversion=4.13.0-37-generic firmware=N/A ip=[REMOVED] latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       recursos: irq:16 memoria:f2000000-f200ffff
```

4) `sudo ethtool enp0s6`:

```
Settings for enp0s6:
    Supported ports: [ MII ]
    Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                            1000baseT/Full 
    Supported pause frame use: No
    Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
    Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                            1000baseT/Full 
    Advertised pause frame use: No
    Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Speed: 1000Mb/s
    Duplex: Full
    Port: MII
    PHYAD: 1
    Transceiver: internal
    Auto-negotiation: on
    Supports Wake-on: g
    Wake-on: d
    Link detected: yes
```

5) `netstat -r` (no ethernet here ...):

```
Tabla de rutas IP del núcleo
Destino         Pasarela        Genmask         Indic   MSS Ventana irtt Interfaz
default         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 wlp3s0
link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 wlp3s0
192.168.1.0     *               255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 wlp3s0
```

6) `sudo vim /etc/network/interfaces`:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

If i tried to add here the `enp0s6` it disappears on the top icon and says: `no cable connection configured`.

7) `ifconfig enp0s6 up`:

```
SIOCSIFFLAGS: Operación no permitida
```

(means not allowed)

8) `sudo dhclient enp0s6`: This never ends and doesn't show anything.

9) `ping 8.8.8.8` is working.

10) Yes, I've tried to change the cable, plug it in another Ethernet switch and the Ethernet is working if I use another computer.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: According to 7), you must use `sudo` when up or down an interface:  `sudo ifconfig enp0s6 up`

Comment: It doesn't say anything and the icon keeps thinking and thinking but never connects.

Comment: Yes, ifconfig up/down usually never says anything. Could it be a hardware issue? I would try to unplug and plugin the cable into the computer, also will try to change the physical port of the cable on the router side if it is possible.

Comment: I've already done that and it doesn't seem to be the problem. I've also used different ethernet cables but, as i've said, the same cable on the same port works on another computer.

Comment: Dear @Dani please  update if the issue has been fixed.